# Weak convergence and pointwise convergence of norm

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Assume that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in some $L^p$ space, and $|f_n|\rightarrow|f|$ pointwise. Does this imply that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise? (or a subsequence?)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with weak convergence, so correct me if I'm wrong. If $f_n(x)=1-1/n$ and we fix $x_0$ to define $g_n(x)=f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x_0)=-f_n(x_0)$ then does $g_n$ converg weakly to the constant $1$? If so then that would be a counterexample.

Comment: could you please hint the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_n(x)=-\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$ and $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$.

Then $|f_n(x)|=|f(x)|$ and $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ since

$$\forall \phi \in L^q, \int (f_n-f)\phi=0,$$

as $f_n-f$ is non-zero over a set of $0$ measure.

Comment: Everything is basically the 0 function in your example I think.

Comment: As an element of $L^p$ space yes. But pointwise convergence makes little sense on those spaces, that is what this answer is telling you. You need to make further assumptions if you want to avoid such cases.

Comment: I think a more interesting example would be $f_n$ not converging to $f$ almost everywhere

Comment: It would be interesting indeed, since there is no such example. Indeed, it would mean that $f_n \to -f$ on a set of non zero measure (where $f$ is non identically $0$). Hence you cannot have weak convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. Just consider $\phi$ as the indicator function of this set. (or a part of it if is has infinite measure) @SorinTirc

Comment: Yup you are right @nicomezi hats off for your solution in this case :D